# Removing duplicate mpatches from a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I startet to work with buttons in my plots (`from matplotlib.widgets import Button`). By pressing the buttons different plots will show up. For that reason my legends do change. I handle this by putting the mpatches in a list:

```
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Numerical average')
handlelist.append(red_patch)
ax.legend(handles=handlelist, numpoints=1)
```

Now if I press the same button twice, the red_patch will also be displayed twice. Because of that I want to delete duplicates but this won't work. So far I tried:

```
list(set(handelist))
```

and also:

```
if red_patch not in handelist:
    handlelist.append(red_patch)
```

But both won't work and I don't understand why. Hope you have an idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Numerical average')
```

creates an instance of `red_patch` every time. The `__eq__` operator seems to be unimplemented for this particular type, so the `set` only compares references of the object, which are not equal.

I would suggest the following code instead:

```
# declare as ordered dict (so order of creation matters), not list
import collections
handlelist = collections.OrderedDict()

color = 'red'
label = 'Numerical average'

if (color,label) not in handlelist:
    handlelist[(color,label)] = mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=label)

# pass the values of the dict as list (legend expects a list)
ax.legend(handles=list(handlelist.values()), numpoints=1)
```

The key of your dictionary is the couple `(color,label)` and when you call the `legend` method you only get one `red_patch`, because if the entry already exists, no extra `Patch` will be created.

Of course, you have to do the same in other parts of your code where you update `handlelist`. A shared method would be handy:

```
def create_patch(color,label):
   if (color,label) not in handlelist:
       handlelist[(color,label)] = mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=label)
```

EDIT: if you have only 1 patch total, you could do even simpler:

```
p = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Numerical average')
ax.legend([p], numpoints=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your code but at the moment I am getting an error: `RCD8.py", line 141, in <module>
    ax.legend(handles=handlelist.values(), numpoints=1)
  File "anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 502, in legend
    for label, handle in zip(labels[:], handles[:]):
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: ooops, I have converted to a `list`, now it should be subscriptable. Also changed the dict as `OrderedDict` just in case creation order matters.

Comment: Thanks that does work now! Just one new problem. I have one reset button, which basically resets the list. With my former code `del handlelist[:]` did the job. Now I get an error. What do I have to change here?

Comment: I thought `del list(handlelist.values())[:]` could work but it doens't

Comment: see my edit. Since you only handle 1 object you don't have to gothrough all this